# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android

I at some date and time when application not active show dialog (activity with Dialog theme; otherwise there is not possibility to do).

```
if (!Utils.isApplicationInForeground(context)) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` => so when I start application after dialog showing through Home button(recent apps) `DialogActivity` is opening instead of Application.

How can I make to open my application?

Comment: Does it happen, when you resume the app (from Recent apps) after you have quit your app by pressing back button?

Answer (score -3):

a silly idea since i don't know what exactly is your purpose, but will work fine

in **DialogActivity.class**,

override method `onResume()` something like,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    DialogActivity.this.finish();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Then dialog will not be shown never.
Even if - I think that application will not be shown then instead of dialog.
------------------------------------
a silly idea since i don't know what exactly is your purpose, but will work fine
1) There is AlarmManager. 01.01.2012 for example the activitydialog is showing through Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK (othewise there is not because app in background). But after dialog was shown I start app through Home Button(click on App screenshot) instead of my app dialog is starting.(If after dialog was shown I start app normally(click on icon) - All is OK)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147144/android-how-to-display-a-dialog-over-a-native-screen

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for someone:
excludeFromRecents="true"  -  it works for me

Comment: @drifter doesn't work for me.Could you please give post the activity element in manifest of your dialog activity